# Optional argument not checked at compile time Haxe

Tags: haxe

I just discovered Haxe tonight and I am happily surprised how developer friendly the syntax is. Quickly understandable, a real joy that it is close to ECMAScript.

```
.
└── src/
    ├── http/
    │   ├── Router.hx
    │   └── Route.hx
    └── Main.hx
```

I have a Router class that declares a "addGetRoute" method, with an optional second parameter:

```
package http;

import http.Route;

class Router
{
    var routes: Array<Route>;

    public function new()
    {
        this.routes = [];   
    }

    public function addGetRoute(route: String, ?handler: () -> String): Void
    {
        this.routes.push(new Route(route, handler));
    }
}
```

This is the Route class content:

```
package http;

class Route
{
    var route: String;
    var handler: () -> String;

    public function new(route: String, handler: () -> String)
    {
        this.route = route;
        this.handler = handler;
    }
}
```

The thing that I don't understand, is that the compiler does not throws an error when seeing this code:

```
this.routes.push(new Route(route, handler));
```

I would expect it throws an error since the second parameter can be null.

Do I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, everything but basic types (`Int`, `Float`, `Bool`) are [nullable](https://haxe.org/manual/types-nullability.html) in Haxe, *including* references to functions (and even basic types are nullable on dynamic targets). While adding `?` to an argument does wrap the type in [`Null<T>`](https://api.haxe.org/Null.html), that doesn't have any effect if the type is already nullable. The primary reason to make an argument ["optional"](https://haxe.org/manual/types-function-optional-arguments.html) with `?` is for it's implied `= null` [default value](https://haxe.org/manual/types-function-default-values.html), which allows skipping it at the call site.

Since Haxe 4, there is actually an opt-in [**null safety**](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-null-safety.html) feature, which enforces that only `Null<T>` is nullable and would thus give you the desired compiler error:

```
@:nullSafety // opt-into null safety
class Main {
    static function main() {
        new Route("example", null);
    }
}
```

> source/Main.hx:4: characters 24-28 : Null safety: Cannot pass nullable value to not-nullable argument "handler" of function "new".

However, do note that null safety is still considered experimental and you might run into some rough edges here and there.